# Using VS 2012 publish profile and Teamcity VS build, I want to build/package once deploy multiple

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy, web.config-transform

I use VS 2012 and Teamcity with Visual Studio Runner type.
My solution has multiple web.config transformation for different environment.
I want to follow continuous delivery, build the solution with multiple packages and using artifacts deploy them to relevant environment when needed without building again.
I don't use MSBuild directly, I use VS package profiles (pubxml)
I would like to have something like this:

> ```
>     <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
>   <PropertyGroup>
>     <WebPublishMethod>Package</WebPublishMethod>
>     <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
>     <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
>     <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
>     <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
>     <DesktopBuildPackageLocation />
>     <PackageAsSingleFile>true</PackageAsSingleFile>
>     <DeployIisAppPath/>
>     <PublishDatabaseSettings/>
>   </PropertyGroup>
>
>   <ItemGroup>
>     <LastUsedBuildConfiguration Include="UAT" />
>     <LastUsedBuildConfiguration Include="APCI" />
>   </ItemGroup> </Project>
> ```

Then I expect the result be two folders in obj of artifact each with their own transformed web.config.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can create multiple transformed configurations in a single build is by using the XDT engine directly during your build process. It's been [available on NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Xdt) for a while now, so it shouldn't be too much hassle.

Having said that, I've been using msdeploy / publish profiles for about two years now and I've since moved to the following:

1. Create an msdeploy package using a `Package.pubxml` and define all your transforms using MSDeploy parameters (which are both more an less powerful than XDT)
2. Create a `PublishProfile.pubxml` file (so you can have the Visual Studio experience) but declare all your parameter values in `PublishProfile.parameters.xml`
3. Perform any "all environments except debug" transforms in a `Web.Release.config` to  avoid overcomplicating your deploy parameters
4. Deploy the package on your build server by calling the generated `.deploy.cmd` (or `msdeploy.exe` directly)

This setup lets you continue to use Visual Studio to publish if you like but you can also move all the way down to the msdeploy commandline, since the `.parameters.xml` file is defined using the msdeploy parameter schema.

Web deploy parameters have plenty of "floating" documentation but no real "reference" home. Here's some useful links:

- [Web Deploy Parameterization](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-parameterization)
- [Reference for the Web Application Package](http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/windows-web-application-gallery/reference-for-the-web-application-package)
- [How to: Use Web Deploy Parameters in a Web Deployment Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398068%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I don't see the different between Package.pubxml and PublishProfile.pubxml now, and also I haven't experimented PublishProfile.parameters.xml. I will have a go and will update.

Comment: Package.pubxml is a publish profile, but its `WebPublishMethod` is set to `Package` rather than `MSDeploy`. The filename is not special, it's just the only obvious choice :)